# server error in .NET application

Tags: asp.net, iis

My website was deployed on IIS using port 80. The network admin made some settings to the certificates making both 80 and 443 accessible. But now when I open my app it opens well but when i open a particular page and click on print button on that page i get the following error:[image: Error]

Can anybody tell me whats wrong here? I have tried changing firewall settings to but no use till now.

Comment: The IP displayed in the error page is the IP of your application?

Comment: yes but my application runs on port 80 and I want to stop ts redirection to 443